# rpy2 cannot find libreadline.6.2.dylib

Tags: python, r, rpy2

[image]

I get this error when I try to import "importr". I guess mainly because they couldn't find the file libreadline.6.2.dylib, I checked the path to the folder and I found only libreadline.8.1.dylib, libreadline.8.dylib and libreadline.dylib.
[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: hey,  since you asked me personally, i looked at your question. sadly i  do things exactly the other way round where i use reticulate to swap data between r & python since python is heavily restricted at my workplace. furthermore i have near 0 experience with mac so file shenanigans are even more difficult for me to trouble shoot.